# Ruby get user input in Index view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I want to create a `number_field` on my `index` view so that way an admin can submit an `id` to a method. How can I do this?

Can I simply use a `form_for` on the `index` view?

Comment: You can use just `form_tag` for that instead of `form_for` since you are not dealing with any model object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use a form partial in your index view. You can then use a submit button or an AJAX action to submit it.

This has some good pointers: https://richonrails.com/articles/partials-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: It tells me that there is an undefined model for `form_for @id do |id|`. I haven't defined `@id` anywhere, but do I need to make a whole model for just an answer I am only using in the `form_for`?

Comment: No, you just need to pass @id from the controller action to the form partial. I assume you would do this in your `index` action. Something like `@id = 0`.